# Burninate [radiation] with fire?

Tags: discussion, tags

[radiation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation) includes questions about [electromagnetic radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) ([example](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/are-personal-electronics-a-risk-to-commercial-aviation)), and also nuclear radiation ([example](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/do-coal-plants-release-more-radiation-than-nuclear-power-plants)).

Should we split them into [electromagnetic-radiation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation) and [nuclear-radiation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuclear-radiation)?

I'm not really that interested in physics, so any physicists who have better names are welcome to suggest them.